# Can someone help me solve this x*y*z=180

Tags: equation-solving

I have one question I've been trying for a while but I can't get the result for my equation..

So I've been trying hard but I can calculate only by hand but the problem is that I am afraid to miss any combination..

So lets get to my equation x*y*z=180 x,y,z should be from [1-10] so which combinations are possible ?

Thanks in advance have a great day

Comment: Is this a question about the software [Mathematica](http://wri.com)?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: It seems you might not have received the traditional welcome, which I extended to you above. I noticed you haven't accept any answers to your question. Please consider whether any of the attempts to help you deserve this token reward.

Answer (score 9):

[`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reduce.html) is able to handle these types of problems:

```
Reduce[x y z == 180 && 1 <= x <= 10 && 1 <= y <= 10 && 1 <= z <= 10, {x, y, z}, Integers]
```

> ```
> (x == 2 && y == 9 && z == 10) || (x == 2 && y == 10 && 
>    z == 9) || (x == 3 && y == 6 && z == 10) || (x == 3 && y == 10 && 
>    z == 6) || (x == 4 && y == 5 && z == 9) || (x == 4 && y == 9 && 
>    z == 5) || (x == 5 && y == 4 && z == 9) || (x == 5 && y == 6 && 
>    z == 6) || (x == 5 && y == 9 && z == 4) || (x == 6 && y == 3 && 
>    z == 10) || (x == 6 && y == 5 && z == 6) || (x == 6 && y == 6 && 
>    z == 5) || (x == 6 && y == 10 && z == 3) || (x == 9 && y == 2 && 
>    z == 10) || (x == 9 && y == 4 && z == 5) || (x == 9 && y == 5 && 
>    z == 4) || (x == 9 && y == 10 && z == 2) || (x == 10 && y == 2 && 
>    z == 9) || (x == 10 && y == 3 && z == 6) || (x == 10 && y == 6 && 
>    z == 3) || (x == 10 && y == 9 && z == 2)
> ```

I don't know if it just brute forces them or does anything smarter.

If you don't want to distinguish `x`, `y`, `z` then add `x <= y <= z` to get a more readable result:

```
Reduce[x y z == 180 && 1 <= x <= 10 && 1 <= y <= 10 && 1 <= z <= 10 &&
   x <= y <= z, {x, y, z}, Integers]
```

> ```
> (x == 2 && y == 9 && z == 10) || (x == 3 && y == 6 && z == 10) || 
> (x == 4 && y == 5 && z == 9) || (x == 5 && y == 6 && z == 6)
> ```

Also take a look at [`FindInstance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindInstance.html).

Of course the key to solving it by hand is factoring the integer: [`FactorInteger`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FactorInteger.html).

Comment: Szabolics (@ is not working for me again...): "I don't know if it just brute forces them..." is something I've wondered about for some time, it certainly seems that way often based on timings. W/B nice if one could specify a method, e.g. hill-climbing, for certain problems.

Comment: @rasher Yes, it would be nice to have user access to the underlying methods in general.

Comment: @Szabolcs I think your answer fits most with providing understanding of how to approach larger more general problem->1+...my aim was based on looking at how to simplify the problem and reducing brute force to a minimum...

Comment: Sometimes using plain `Reduce` in similar problems does not return explicit solutions, if the number of solutions is too large. In these cases, using `FindInstance` and explicitly specifying maximum amount of solutions to seek may help.

Answer (score 5):

I only post this given the relatively small size of the problem.
The factors of 180 (including multiplicity): 2,2,3,3,5

By inspection any collection of three (or more) factors will exceed 10. This means 1 x num1 xnum2 cannot be a solution as  one of the num will have three or more  of the factors above.

Further, partitioning the set of five factors into three subsets: 2,2,1 or 3,1,1. Hence we only need consider partitions of form 2,2,1.

So:

```
f = {2, 2, 3, 3, 5};
perm = Permutations[f];
Cases[Union[
  Sort /@ ({Times @@ #[[1 ;; 2]], Times @@ #[[3 ;; 4]], #[[5]]} & /@ 
     perm)], Table[_?(# < 11 &), {3}]]
```

yields:

```
{{2, 9, 10}, {3, 6, 10}, {4, 5, 9}, {5, 6, 6}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Given the small size of the problem, brute force works just fine..

```
 Select[Sort/@Tuples[Range[10],{3}]//Union,Times@@#==180&]
```

> {{2,9,10},{3,6,10},{4,5,9},{5,6,6}}

This is about 5x faster than the `Reduce` solution..

Comment: Following 21 combinations are possible: > {2,9,10}, {2,10,9}, {3,6,10}, {3,10,6}, {4,5,9}, {4,9,5}, {5,4,9}, {5,6,6}, {5,9,4}, {6,3,10}, {6,5,6}, {6,6,5}, {6,10,3}, {9,2,10}, {9,4,5}, {9,5,4}, {9,10,2}, {10,2,9}, {10,3,6}, {10,6,3}, {10,9,2},

Answer (score 1):

Working directly with the factors like ubpdqn, but somewhat different approach. Not efficient, but straightforward to understand:

```
factors = {2, 2, 3, 3, 5}; 
perms = Permutations[factors];
```

Now by mapping `ReplaceList` over `perms` with the replacement rule in the code that follows, we can partition each list in `perms` into every possible partition of three sublists, and while we're at it, apply `Times` to the sequence of numbers in each sublist, followed by `Sort` to the resulting list of three numbers (so we can delete duplicates in the next step): A lot of redundant cases are generated by this approach, but it's a small example so I'm not really concerned about efficiency here.

```
ReplaceList[#, {x__Integer, y__Integer, z__Integer} :> Sort@{Times@x, 
     Times@y, Times@z}] & /@ perms
```

Now we can use `Flatten` to remove one level of braces, and also `DeleteDuplicates`:

```
DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[%, 1]]
```

This gives 
`{{2, 2, 45}, {2, 6, 15}, {2, 5, 18}, {3, 4, 15}, {4, 5, 9}, {3, 5, 
  12}, {2, 3, 30}, {2, 9, 10}, {3, 3, 20}, {5, 6, 6}, {3, 6, 10}}`

You can further eliminate unwanted cases using `Select` as below:

```
Select[%, Max[#] <= 10 &]
```

and you get

> {{4, 5, 9}, {2, 9, 10}, {5, 6, 6}, {3, 6, 10}}

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to calculate the solutions, as several people have already suggested:

```
Reduce[x*y*z == 180 && 10 >= x >= 1 && 10 >= y >= 1 && 10 >= z >= 1, {x, y, z}, Integers]
```

> (x==2 && y==9 && z==10) || (x==2 && y==10 && z==9) || (x==3 && y==6 && z==10) ||
>
> (x==3 && y==10 && z==6) || (x==4 && y==5 && z==9) || (x==4 && y==9 && z==5) ||
>
> (x==5 && y==4 && z==9) || (x==5 && y==6 && z==6) || (x==5 && y==9 && z==4) ||
>
> (x==6 && y==3 && z==10) || (x==6 && y==5 && z==6) || (x==6 && y==6 && z==5) ||
>
> (x==6 && y==10 && z==3) || (x==9 && y==2 && z==10) || (x==9 && y==4 && z==5) ||
>
> (x==9 && y==5 && z==4) || (x==9 && y==10 && z==2) || (x==10 && y==2 && z==9) ||
>
> (x==10 && y==3 && z==6) || (x==10 && y==6 && z==3) || (x==10 && y==9 && z==2)

```
Solve[x*y*z == 180 && 10 >= x >= 1 && 10 >= y >= 1 && 10 >= z >= 1, {x, y, z}, Integers]
```

> {{x->2,y->9,z->10},{x->2,y->10,z->9},{x->3,y->6,z->10},
>
> {x->3,y->10,z->6},{x->4,y->5,z->9},{x->4,y->9,z->5},
>
> {x->5,y->4,z->9},{x->5,y->6,z->6},{x->5,y->9,z->4},
>
> {x->6,y->3,z->10},{x->6,y->5,z->6},{x->6,y->6,z->5},
>
> {x->6,y->10,z->3},{x->9,y->2,z->10},{x->9,y->4,z->5},
>
> {x->9,y->5,z->4},{x->9,y->10,z->2},{x->10,y->2,z->9},
>
> {x->10,y->3,z->6},{x->10,y->6,z->3},{x->10,y->9,z->2}}

```
FindInstance[x*y*z==180 && 10>=x>=1 && 10>=y>=1 && 10>=z>= 1, {x,y,z}, Integers]
```

> {{x->2,y->9,z->10}}

You can choose an order if you want x>=y>=z as:

```
Solve[{x*y*z == 180 && 10 >= x >= y >= z >= 1}, {x, y, z}, Integers]
```

> {{x->6,y->6,z->5},{x->9,y->5,z->4},{x->10,y->6,z->3},{x->10,y->9,z->2}}